# When i use my Zend_Db_Table_Abstract with select and join, fetchAll return me one row

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, join

I have a problem with my class (extend by Zend_Db_Table_Abstract), it returns with only one row each time with a join and select....

I searched on the internet but I found nothing on this "bug"!

```
class Api_Model_News extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
protected $_name = 'news';
protected $_primary = 'news_id';

protected $select;

public function init()
{
  $this->select = $this->select();
}

public function setTimestamp($timestamp)
{
  $this->select
    ->where('news_timestamp >= ?', $timestamp);
  return $this;
}
public function setCategory($id_category)
{
  $this->select
    ->where('bsn_id_category = ?', $id_category);
  return $this;
}

public function getNews()
{
  $this->select
    ->from('news')
    ->joinLeft('business', 'news_id = bsn_id', array());
  $data = $this->fetchAll($this->select);
  return $data->toArray();
}

}
```

In another function:

```
$news = new Api_Model_News();                    

if ($id_category != NULL)
  $news->setCategory($id_category);

if ($last_sync != NULL)
  $news->setTimestamp($last_sync);

return $news->getNews();
```

- When I set `id_category` and not `last_sync` => Only ONE row
- When I set `last_sync` and not `id_category` => Multiples rows
- When I set `last_sync` and `id_category` => Only ONE row

Why? I suppose it's because I use `bsn_id_category` in `select` but I don't understand ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the last answer, try this:

```
 $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->joinLeft('business', 'news_id = bsn_id', array());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the integrity check to false as `"Setting this flag to false skips the checks for table joins, allowing 'hybrid' table rows to be created"`:

```
  $this->select
       ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->joinLeft('business', 'news_id = bsn_id', array());
```